# mysql to csv without using INTO OUTFILE of mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fwrite, fputcsv

I need to export data from mysql to a csv file with column heading but i dont have file permission on the server. Is there any otherway to do it? i.e. using php fwrite? or fputcsv?

Any help will be much appriciate.

Thanks.

Comment: `fputcsv` was made for it so... yeah... erm.... use that

Comment: Hi thanks, Is it possible to give detail example? I am not expert on this things. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to the MySQL server, you can run the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) utility, which is capable of generating CSV files. This is far easier than trying to come up with something yourself.

```
mysqldump --tab --fields-terminated-by="," --host=$SERVER --user=$USERNAME --password=$PASSWORD $DATABASE
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response mr Michael Mior where it will save the file? Is there a way to specify a file name for output?

Comment: The file will get written to standard output. If you want to save to a file, just redirect by adding ` > filename` to the end.

Comment: It is specifically stated that the user doesn't have _FILE_ permission on the mysql server. mysqldump _--tab_ option uses _SELECT INTO OUTFILE_ which requires this permission. This answer therefore will not work in the given situation.