# Is it possible to export to CSV from MYSQL without using SELECT INTO OUTFILE?

Tags: mysql, csv

I couldn't find anything in documentation on this topic.
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You should tell why you don't want to use  `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql to csv without using INTO OUTFILE of mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835750/mysql-to-csv-without-using-into-outfile-of-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, PHPMyAdmin version 4 onwards does this (and possibly before).

Using PHPMyAdmin:

On your table select "EXPORT" and then choose "SHOW ALL OPTIONS" and then select "OUTPUT AS TEXT" and select the format you want "CSV for MS Excel" and bang, there you have CSV text output of your table.

Unfortunately I can't find the core MySQL coding to do this, though.